# Adding Gallery page to Magento website

Tags: magento2, extensions

I want to add a page on Magento 2 where I can display photos. Not the product photos but any photo that I want to display can be added. Thanks.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create a CMS Page**

https://magefan.com/blog/create-cms-page-in-magento-2

**Add Pictures to Page Using Page Builder**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjJrshQ0Is4&t=195s

**Update**

You can Add Gallery with page Builder By creating `3 Rows` X `4 Columns` X `1 Image`

[image]

Comment: Hi Waqar,
Really thanks for such a wonderful explanation links. I really appreciate your efforts but I already have created a page but I want to add photo gallery to it. Something like this https://ibb.co/n36pkFL. Thanks

Comment: can you add image in question i can't access this image link

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you have a look?

Comment: The Page you have uploaded is actually PLP (Product Listing Page) you can create such page by creating new Category Named Gallery

Then Assign Products to it and Add a Static Block on the top of the page


Add the Gallery to Block Using Page Builder

Comment: It was just an example. other things i can do, just wanted to know how to add gallery via pages builder.

Comment: check updated Answer

Comment: Perfect it worked. Just one more query. The photos are added is there a way to add some zoom in effect when hover over images on gallery page? Thanks